# Same workbook in two windows; Sub changes which tab is viewed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that uses a macro to add extra lines, as the workbook has to be heavily locked down to protect it from users. I'm using Excel 2010.

However, if I have two windows open looking at different sheets of the workbook, running the macro makes both windows shift to the sheet in which I added the lines(s), which is disruptive to workflow.

My guess is that this is down to using .PasteSpecial but I am unsure of how else to do it, as the lines to be added include formatting and formulae so .value = .value won't work.

The sub is called from one of four other subs; one to add a single row, one to add multiple rows,  one to add a special header row, and one that adds costs rows (done by sending a negative number of rows). The code is:

```
Sub InsertAnyRows(NumRows As Integer)

    Dim thisWS As Worksheet
    Set thisWS = ActiveSheet
    If Not (InRange(ActiveCell, thisWS.Range("QuoteLines")) Or InRange(ActiveCell, thisWS.Range("LabourLines")) Or InRange(ActiveCell, thisWS.Range("OptionsLines"))) Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Dim RowLoc As Range
    Set RowLoc = thisWS.Cells(Selection.Rows(1).Row, 1)

    Select Case NumRows

        Case Is < 0 ' must be inserting costs rows
            NumRows = NumRows * -1
            RowLoc.Resize(NumRows).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            thisWS.Range("CostsBlankRow").Copy
            RowLoc.Resize(NumRows).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

        Case 0 ' must be inserting a header row
            RowLoc.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            thisWS.Range("TabHeaderRow").Copy
            RowLoc.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

        Case Else ' must be inserting normal rows
            RowLoc.Resize(NumRows).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            thisWS.Range("TabBlankRow").Copy
            RowLoc.Resize(NumRows).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

    End Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather messy and I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but in a quick test adding these lines after `End Select` seemed to preserve the windows.

```
Windows(1).Activate
thisWS.Activate
Windows(2).Activate
Sheets(2).Activate 'adjust sheet name/index to suit
```

Comment: Ah - so revert to the previous view - that seems a simple solution. I will try this out and let you know - thank you.

Comment: I took your suggestion as a starting point and revised the code a bit so that it can deal with an arbitrary number of windows (possibly overengineering).

Comment: The code is too big to post in comments; should I amend the question to show the solution?

Comment: Yes, post as an answer if that's what did the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, so that it'll deal with an arbitrary number of open windows; it also reselects whatever the selection was before running the macro (which looks neater to me). Thank you for the pointers!

```
Sub InsertAnyRows(NumRows As Integer)

    Dim thisWS As Worksheet
    Set thisWS = ActiveSheet
    If Not (InRange(ActiveCell, thisWS.Range("QuoteLines")) Or InRange(ActiveCell, thisWS.Range("LabourLines")) Or InRange(ActiveCell, thisWS.Range("OptionsLines"))) Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Dim NumWindows As Integer
    NumWindows = ThisWorkbook.Windows.Count

    If NumWindows > 1 Then

        Dim Windows() As Window
        Dim WindowsSheets() As Worksheet

        ReDim Windows(NumWindows)
        ReDim WindowsSheets(NumWindows)

        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 1 To NumWindows
            Set Windows(i) = ThisWorkbook.Windows(i)
            Set WindowsSheets(i) = Windows(i).ActiveSheet
        Next i

    End If

    Dim RowLoc As Range, EndLoc As Range, SelRange As Range
    Set SelRange = Selection
    Set RowLoc = thisWS.Cells(Selection.Rows(1).Row, 1)

    Select Case NumRows

        Case Is < 0 ' must be inserting costs rows
            NumRows = NumRows * -1
            RowLoc.Resize(NumRows).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            thisWS.Range("CostsBlankRow").Copy
            RowLoc.Resize(NumRows).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

        Case 0 ' must be inserting a header row
            RowLoc.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            thisWS.Range("TabHeaderRow").Copy
            RowLoc.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

        Case Else ' must be inserting normal rows
            RowLoc.Resize(NumRows).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            thisWS.Range("TabBlankRow").Copy
            RowLoc.Resize(NumRows).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

    End Select

    SelRange.Select

    If NumWindows > 1 Then

        For i = NumWindows To 1 Step -1
            Windows(i).Activate
            WindowsSheets(i).Activate
        Next i

    End If

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```